# Get the root DOM node of a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

`findDOMNode` can be used to find the DOM node of a given Component, but I'm not sure how to traverse the tree to find the same node that was passed initially to `ReactDOM.render()`.

e.g.

Discover the element `root` from inside App, where we have:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Does React store this internally?

Comment: Sound like XY problem https://xyproblem.info/, what is the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there might be multiple React application running on the same page (*different versions / microfrontends*) and so, I don't know of a why from within a specific one of them to know which container belongs to it, but there is a way to find the root container, **assuming** it's a direct child node of the `<body>` element:

```js
const root = [...document.body.children].find(elem => elem._reactRootContainer)
```

Answer (score -3):

Why exactly are you trying to find the element with the `"root"` id? The second argument of the `render` function is getting that element just so you know.

But the real question is do you want the React component or the actual DOM element it's been bound too, since everything after this is the VDOM (Virual DOM).

Comment: My naive guess is that you want to access state in a component higher in the hierarchy, this isn't possible without passing state mutable methods through every single parent component. Checkout the Context API or a global state management library such as Redux or MobX, there are others as well.

Comment: I want to measure the tree depth between some inner component and the top level component, preferably without wrapping components.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a mere comment asking for the reason, which does not matter. I have the exact same question, and many come here with their own reasons for knowing which node is the root node.